# Getting undefined values after service call angular 2

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular-services

I am getting undefined value to a variable in angular 2. I have a function which calls a service which provides data to initialize a variable, now i provide this variable to another function which does a get http request. And get request in unable to process as the variable in undefined.

Code:

```
variable:any;
constructor(private http: Http, private serviceOne: ServiceOne){
function1();    //service call to get data
function2();    //http get request
}

function1(){
calls request  //subscribes data
data =>{this.variable = data.var};
}

function2(){
console.log(this.variable);   //undefined
http get request uses this.variable
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your function1() does an async call for setting data to this. Variable. If this is the case, you have to wait for the async function to complete before moving to function2().

Try to do

```
variable:any;
constructor(private http: Http, private serviceOne: ServiceOne){
function1();    //service call to get data
}

function1(){
yourAsyncCall(). subscribe(res=>{
this.function2(res);
}) 
}

function2(variable){
this.variable=variable ;
//Use variable in your http requeat
}
```

Comment: How do I make it synchronous? @Gili

Comment: It's depends on your data source, but if it been fetched from server it can't be synchronous. http request by it's nature is asynchronous. Why do you want it to be  synchronous?